# Ranking date column in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rank

I have the following data frame in pyspark:

```
>>> df.show()
+----------+------+
|  date_col|counts|
+----------+------+
|2022-02-05|350647|
|2022-02-06|313091|
+----------+------+
```

I want to create a resultant data frame which ranks the date_col in increasing order:

```
>>> df.show()
+----------+------+---------+
|  date_col|counts|order_col|
+----------+------+---------+
|2022-02-05|350647|        2| 
|2022-02-06|313091|        1|
+----------+------+---------+
```

How can we achieve this?

Following script can be used to created dataframe df:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(date_col=date(2022, 02, 05), count=350647 ),
    Row(date_col=date(2022, 02, 06), count=313091 ),
])
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with [Rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rank.html) , in conjunction with [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html)

#### Data Preparation

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sql = SQLContext(sc)


d = {
        'date_col':['2022-02-05', '2022-02-06', '2022-02-07', '2022-02-08'],
        'counts':[350647, 313091, 317791, 312145],
    }

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d))

sparkDF.show()

+----------+------+
|  date_col|counts|
+----------+------+
|2022-02-05|350647|
|2022-02-06|313091|
|2022-02-07|317791|
|2022-02-08|312145|
+----------+------+
```

#### Rank

```
window = Window.orderBy(F.col('date_col').desc())
    
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('order_col',F.rank().over(window))

sparkDF.show()

+----------+------+---------+
|  date_col|counts|order_col|
+----------+------+---------+
|2022-02-08|312145|        1|
|2022-02-07|317791|        2|
|2022-02-06|313091|        3|
|2022-02-05|350647|        4|
+----------+------+---------+
```

#### Rank - SparkSQL

```
sql.sql(
    """
    SELECT
         date_col
        ,counts
        ,RANK() OVER( ORDER BY date_col DESC) as order_col
    FROM TB1
    """
).show()

+----------+------+---------+
|  date_col|counts|order_col|
+----------+------+---------+
|2022-02-08|312145|        1|
|2022-02-07|317791|        2|
|2022-02-06|313091|        3|
|2022-02-05|350647|        4|
+----------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vaebhav, your answer worked perfectly. Can you also explain what's the use of creating `window` variable? And this variable is created without even defining the dataframe whose `date_col` it needs to pick, that's a bit confusing? Thanks again.

Comment: For `Window` Explanation kindly go through - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html

In a nutshell , since `rank` is an analytical function , it requires a unbounded/bounded range to work with

Comment: Regarding how , `date_col` was tagged to the DataFrame its present within the code snippet - `Window.orderBy(F.col('date_col').desc())`

Try changing the column value to a non existence column and you ll understand